# Is there some way to sync only Reminders to iCloud?

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud, macos, reminders

Under Mountain Lion, syncing Reminders to iCloud is linked to syncing Calendars for some reason:

[image]

In contrast, under iOS (version 5), you're able to sync Reminders to iCloud separately:

[image]

I sync my Calendars to a Google Calendar, and my Reminders to iCloud on my iOS devices.  However, in Mountain Lion, this doesn't seem to be possible.

#### Is there some workaround to the limitation in the preference pane in OS X?

Comment: FWIW, this is not an issue in Mavericks.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a hidden issue in Mavericks. Though Apple gives separate tickboxes for Calendars and Reminders, it still syncs them together or not at all.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Just add your google account from System Preferences as usual. Then open iCal > Preferences > Accounts > iCloud and untick "Enable this account"

[image]

Comment: This didn't work.  Reminders isn't pulling down my iCloud Reminders.

Comment: @Keen, make sure Calendars & Reminders is still checked.

Answer (score 1):

This works.. one more thing to make it safe - i.e. to retain your google calendar without a fuss..

- **Disable WIFI or unplug your Ethernet cable**
- enable Reminders & Calendar in the Cloud Setting in Mountain Lion
- Open iCal, and iCal will attempt to Sync w/ iCloud and will eventually timeout
- click "Try Again Later"
- In iCal go to Preferences > Accounts > iCloud and untick "Enable this account"
- Enable your WIFI/plug in your Ethernat cable

Comment: Additional note.. everything seems to be setup, but the reminders are still not syncing w/ iCloud. However the Google Calendar is still syncing as normal..

Answer (score 0):

I, too, would very much like the OSX Reminders to be sync'd with iCloud separately from Calendar (I, too, sync my Calendar with Google Calendars).  In testing out Keen's response, I found that if I leave my OSX Calendar enabled in iCloud, then look in OSX Reminders, I see all the same tasks as on my iOS devices. On my OSX Reminders, I added a task to one of the iCloud lists. Then, once again, disabled the iCloud Calendar account. Now, when I look at my iOS device, the task I added while on my Mac is there (and alerted me on my iOS device at the appropriate time).

So, temporarily enabling the OSX Calendar/Reminders sync with iCloud is a work-around...certainly not pretty, but do-able...until Apple improves OSX to separate the Reminders iCloud sync from the Calendar iCloud sync.